# Play music file using Batch?

Tags: batch-file, audio, cmd

I am very confused as to how one would go about this. I want to use Batch to start an .mp3 file and while typing    start file.mp3    plays the file, it opens the Media Player to do so. How would I play a music file in the background, but also have the ability to stop it whenever I please?

Comment: Batch (on its own) does not have the ability to play audio files. You'll want to use it to start another application and supply arguments to it.

Comment: Take a look at PowerShell. It's a replacement for what you call "batch". It's far more powerful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Windows Media Player* with all its bells and whistles is not suitable for noninteractive listening. Use older version instead, which opens just a small window with a few necessary controls, plays the file and exits:

```
Mplay32.exe /Play /Close "file.mp3"
```

You may find more inspiration at 
http://vitsoft.info/skimid3.htm#TalkingPlayer