# Detect media player playing via cmd

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, media-player, system-shutdown

How can I detect if a media player has stopped playing?

Please answer for Windows Media Player. I need it to detect via cmd\bat.

All I need to do is close Windows Media Player after playing a playlist. so 
far i have:

```
start wmplayer.exe /play /playlist "NiteTime Listener Playlist"
```

Basically I'm making a program where I can place certain files in a specific 
playlist in Windows Media Player, and then open the program, and it play all 
the files, then shuts down the PC.

So far, I've set up starting WMP(Windows Media Player), playing The Playlist, then detecting if WMP is open, if it is not, it shuts down the PC.

If it is, it detects again, in a loop.

Only problem is closing WMP after playlist complete.

Here is a My Entire Code:

```
@echo off
title Automatic Shutdown for NiteTime Listener
echo To cancel Shutdown, close this program before Player.
start mplayer2.exe /play /Playlist "NiteTime Listener Playlist"
:testfor
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq wmplayer.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "wmplayer.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" goto :ProgramRunning
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="1" goto :ProgramNotRunning
pause

:ProgramRunning
goto testfor

:ProgramNotRunning
shutdown /s /f
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Media Player doesn't support closing automatically when media playback stops.<sup>1</sup> And it doesn't include any command line options for controlling or reading the status of existing player processes.

There are at least four options available.

1. If you want to stick with Windows Media Player, you could write a basic application that embeds the Windows Media Player ActiveX control. (Probably about 100-150 lines of code, mostly boilerplate generated automatically when you create the project.)
2. Use VLC and add `vlc://quit` to the end of your playlist.

   m3u Playlist

   ```
   #EXTM3U
   C:\Path\To\My\Media\File1.mp3
   C:\Path\To\My\Media\File2.mp3
   vlc://quit
   ```

   XSPF Playlist

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <playlist version="1" xmlns="http://xspf.org/ns/0/">
      <trackList>
        <track><location>file:///C:\Path\To\My\Media\File1.mp3</location></track>
        <track><location>file:///C:\Path\To\My\Media\File2.mp3</location></track>
        <track><location>vlc://quit</location></track>
      </trackList>
   </playlist>
   ```

   Launch VLC with the command line:

   ```
   start /wait "C:\path\to\vlc.exe" "c:\path\to\playlist\file.m3u"
   ```
3. Use a utility like AutoIt to control the media player instance via its user interface.
4. Use/Modify the [ScriptableWMPlayer](https://github.com/thebecwar/ScriptableWMPlayer) that I wrote. It embeds the Windows Media Player ActiveX control and has some basic command line control.<sup>2</sup>

---

*<sup>1</sup>[As of 2011](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-pictures/close-media-player-automatically-after-a-file/d856aec8-aedf-4dc4-8a2a-d08cdc611006) the official party line was that this was by design.*

*<sup>2</sup>Pull requests and bug reports are welcome.*

Comment: Thanks for that answer, I'll look into the vlc player.

Comment: I am now having the EXACT same problem as before, except now I'm using VLC. so far, no matter WHERE I look, nothing works --play and exit vlc:\\quit, vlc:quit, NOTHING works. btw, I am on WINDOWS. So Command Prompt, rather than Command-line.

Comment: `vlc://quit` uses forward slashes, not back slashes, play and exit is `--play-and-exit`. At a command prompt try: `start /wait vlc.exe "c:\path\to\some\media\file" vlc://quit`. If that works let me know and I'll edit the answer with a demo m3u playlist. Also, I realize you're on windows, hence the repeated "_Windows_ Media Player" references. Command prompt refers to `cmd.exe` while command line refers more generally to the options passed to an executable at the time its started.

Comment: Use an older version 5.1 of _Windows Media Player_ from Windows XP which exits when the song is over:
 Mplay32.exe /Play /Close "file.mp3"
See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27476035/play-music-file-using-batch/27481065

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. one thing is, i can't simply type

Comment: @TechnoCraft no worries. If that works for you (which I expect it will) I'll expand the VLC section a bit to show a couple examples of how you can use it.

Comment: CODE: vlc       to use the vlc parameters i have to use the path. so C:\Users\Name\Desktop\vlc. oh,and i HAVE to use a playlist, but i cannot figure out how to do "vlc --playlist Playlist" I have to do C:\Users\Micahp\Desktop\Playlist.xspf" and tha starts the playlist. But it will not work adding a quit method. I have copy/pasted off many sites, and yes, i have used vlc://quit and vlc:\\quit and even tried C:\Users\Name\Desktop\vlc://quit I do have one last idea though, and that is  C:\Users\Micahp\Desktop\Playlist.xspf://quit.

Comment: @TechnoCraft I added sample playlists that show `vlc://quit` in action